# Owl Carousel loading issue when within the WordPress loop

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, owl-carousel-2

I am currently displaying 12 random products from WooCommerce, using the owl carousel slider, when the page loads there seems to be a delay before owl calculates everything resulting in a "springboarding" type effect.

I have done some testing in relation to using a generic owl carousel, with static content and it renders fine on page load, but with the introduction to pulling data from a WordPress loop this is where the issues lies!

Same http://preview.meeko.me/product/navy-floral-print-pleat-skater-dress/

This is the owl-carousel call:

```
var meekoRelated = $('#relatedSlider');
meekoRelated.owlCarousel({
    lazyLoad: true,
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    nav: true,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items: 2
        },              
        640:{
            items: 4
        },
        1000:{
            items: 5
        }
    }
});
```

My loop into Woocommerce

```
            <div id="relatedSlider" class="owl-caroucel">

             <?php
             $args = array( 
             'post_type' => 'product', 
             'orderby' => 'rand',
             'posts_per_page' => 12 
             );
             $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
             while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

                <div class="categoryarchivegrid">    

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'rec' ); ?>

                </div>

             <?php endwhile; ?>
             <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

            </div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do exactly mean by "springboarding" effekt? To prevent the slider to be collapsed if the carousel is not loaded yet, you can give it a fixed height with css.

Comment: It is when all slides load at once then springs back to one line - I will set a height and see if that resolves the issue!

Comment: Sadly no joy, even when setting a height for the carousel

Comment: Did you try it like this? `.owl-carousel .owl-item { min-height: 300px;}`. I don't see this effect on the site that you have linked and never experienced it when I've used owl carousel. Do you have the same issue if you disable **lazyLoad**?

Comment: It does seem intermitant, it happens both on local and producition - i'll add min-height and see what happens

Comment: I think that what you are seeing is probably [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content). I see it here on every page load. The selected answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329878/remove-flash-of-unstyled-content-fouc) suggests setting CSS height and width and `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: BTW: `min-height` would have a negative effect.

Comment: Thats the exact symptom! I've tried hiding the carousel and showing it once the page loads, but sometimes the carousel briefly displays still before showing it with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the problem, it is all down to my bad spelling! I was using the class "owl-caroucel" and on page load it was adding "owl-carousel".. so if the page took a while to load it would load unstyled with FOUC as Roamer-1888 suggested.